# Responsive image in HTML with max width/height and without CSS

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

Is there a way to add an in-line image using HTML that is responsive but has a max width?

I know that I can use `<img width="100%" />` to make it responsive, but this results in the image resizing to the container size, and I want to set a max width/size for it.

Is this possible? The reason I don't want to do it using CSS is because in this instance I can't edit the master/parent CSS and would rather not use in-line CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope.  CSS is what provides 'responsive' capabilities

Comment: You could attempt to use inline styling and use the keyword !important, that may over write the CSS rules

Comment: you can set `max-width` to the container of the `img`

Comment: `<img style="max-width:100%;">`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Using `<img style="max-width:100%;">` works as long as the actual size of the image is not larger than I want it to appear on desktop/larger screens, so that's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not looking to set the percentage, then use this:

`<img style="max-width: 200px;">`

However I like to set it like this:

`<img style="max-width: calc(100% - 20px);">`

this way you can set the img to certain px smaller than its container. either one will work.

Answer (score 1):

My most common need for intelligently choosing width would be to size something to 100% unless that gets too big. For example, specify both width and max-width:

`<img src="myimage.png" style="max-width:1000px;  width:100%;">`

That is inline-CSS, which the original question states is not desired; however, the OP then chose a solution which was inline CSS.